# Wazuh Plugin for kibana 7.17.x version

Tags: kibana, elk, wazuh

I'm trying to install wazuh on kibana. But i found proble where my kibana version is not compatible with wazuh latest version (7.14.x) based on this repo https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh-kibana-app. Is there wazuh plugin for kibana 7.17.2 version?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hope you're doing well.

[Here](https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh-kibana-app#wazuh---kibana---open-distro-version-compatibility-matrix) you can find more information about compatibility between Wazuh and Kibana.
At this moment, there's no compatible version of Wazuh plugin for the Kibana version you have.

The solution here is downgrading Kibana to the latest working version, which is `7.14.2`. It will properly work with [Wazuh Plugin `7.14.2`](https://packages.wazuh.com/4.x/ui/kibana/wazuh_kibana-4.2.5_7.14.2-1.zip) and Wazuh `4.2.5`.

Regards,
Alexis.